# How to use Javascript libraries with Lightning Web Security in Aura components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, libraries, lightning-web-security

We are using the Leaflet Javascript library to add mapping to our application. Currently we have the following:

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.Leaflet + '/leaflet.css'}"
              scripts="{!$Resource.Leaflet + '/leaflet.js'}"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}" />
```

Before turning on Lightning Web Security, we could reference Leaflet in the controller and helper by doing something like:

```
let layerGroup = L.layerGroup();
```

However, after turning on LWS, we get the error `L is not defined`

Is there anything we need to add to make this work?

Comment: LWS shouldn't impact your ability to use Leaflet. I remember using it before just fine, but I don't recall where I left that source code. Have you tried `window.L` instead? That might help.

Comment: @sfdcfox window.L is undefined unfortunately

Comment: What about your browser's Developer Console (F12)? Any errors there? Have you tried using F12's Sources tab and using the "break on handled exceptions" feature? It would be helpful if you could try and find anything weird.

Comment: @sfdcfox the only error I can find is "L is not defined"

Comment: We're experiencing the same issue now that Spring '23 enables this by default in scratch orgs.  Our app uses CometD for platform event subscriptions in lightning components and it's no longer working with LWS enabled, the expected object is no longer available.  We can't switch to empApi as that doesn't work on mobile devices.

Comment: @E.J.Wilburn We did the exact same thing with CometD and are experiencing the same...

Comment: Try again. Salesforce have told me that the issue has been fixed.

Comment: Confirmed it's now fixed for me, though you might need to recreate your scratch org if you still see the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce have said this was a bug relating to `ltng:require` and it has been fixed as of late last week.